# looping until enter zero in java

Tags: java, eclipse

i want from my code if user enter number zero is stop

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choose_num =1;
    Functions fun = new Functions();
    while (choose_num != 0) {
        System.out.println("Hello My Friend, Please choose one: \n");
        System.out.println("1 for Calculator \n2 for compairing \n" +
                            "3 for calculate factorial\n" +
                            "0 for exit");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            choose_num = in.nextInt();
            switch (choose_num) {
            case 1: fun.add_two_number();
                break;
            case 2: fun.compaire();
                break;
            case 3: fun.factorial();
                break;
            default: choose_num = 0;
                break;
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

first time is run but when it return to start i give error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at MyFirstProgram.main(MyFirstProgram.java:27)
```

i am using eclipse on ubuntu please help me

thanks

Comment: Read: [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Three questions - (1) Did you actually type a number?  (2) Could one of the other methods that you call perhaps do some input, but not consume all of the intended input - for example, you type two words and it reads just one?  (3) Did you learn anything when you stepped through this with your debugger before posting the question?

Comment: Somebody needs to write an article: _Stack Overflow as a (free) debugging service._

Comment: Actually, what needs to happen is that all those professors who teach first year programming courses need to introduce the use of a debugger earlier in their curriculum (if they do so at all).  I suspect that some of them are academics who haven't ever written "real world" code.

Comment: Need to **Debug** to find your **Bug**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You close your Scanner too early.
Remove `in.close()` line, or move it outside of cycle.

Comment: Perfect answer.  This is an object lesson in why you should line your curly braces up properly.

Comment: @Basilevs i am comment line in.close() but same problem

Comment: Try moving `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` to before the `while` statement.

Comment: Ok thanks i am remove all in.close() from functions and its work. thanks